# How to call a method from a class that takes interfaces as parameters?

Tags: c#

From a unit test I need to call method `GetAvailableProducts` in the following class:

```
public class ProductProvider : IProductProvider
{
    private readonly IProductService _service;
    private readonly IElasticSearchService _elasticSearchService;

    public ProductProvider(IProductService service, IElasticSearchService elasticSearchService)
    {
        _service = service;
        _elasticSearchService = elasticSearchService;
    }

    public PageResult<Product> GetAvailableProducts(ProductSearchRequest request)
    {
        return _elasticSearchService.GetProducts(request);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the class takes interfaces as parameters, and I can't figure out how to properly instantiate it. I have tried the following:

```
public static class Searcher
{
    private static readonly IProductService _service;
    private static readonly IElasticSearchService _elasticSearchService;
    private static readonly IProductProvider _pp = new ProductProvider(_service, _elasticSearchService);

    public static PageResult<Product> GetData()
    {
        ...

        return _pp.GetAvailableProducts(request);
    }
}
```

When the debugger gets to `_elasticSearchService.GetProducts(request)`, of course it throws out a 'null object reference' error for _elasticSearchService. How do I correctly instantiate the class?

Comment: Test as in a Unit Test or test as in you are learning code and you want to see how you can make this call or test as in something else?

Comment: That test (as a Unit Test) would be pretty senseless. In the end you would be testing `GetProducts` of one specific implementation, only. Which should already have been tested. You _could_ inject a mock to make sure `GetProducts` will be called, but that's about it.

Comment: @Igor as a unit test.

Comment: You need to mock/stub those instances. There are many frameworks out there that can do this for you like NSubstitute or Moq or Fakeiteasy. You can then define their behavior and check if their members have been accessed and with what values.

Comment: BTW: The naming of that method seems a little odd to me, since it is implying some sort of filter will be applied that lets trough only available products. But in fact it just passes on the request with all its properties ... not related to the question, just something that jumped into my eye.

Comment: @Fildor, it's not a proper unit test. I need to check if the data retrieved is correct and as expected.

Comment: @Smk That's not what you _can_ test here.

Comment: ... If you were to do it here, you would only test one specific implementation of that interface. Which should already be tested elsewhere (namely in the tests for that respective class). See, your expected output depends on the implementation of the interface. So that would be not quite right to do here. Your function under test is a relay, so test the relay. If you get the expected result has nothing to do with _this_ function.

Comment: What you _can_ test: If `_elasticSearchService` is null, you expect a NRE. If it is not null, you expect `GetProducts` to be called on its implementation. That. is. it. The first can be tested independently, the second can be tested by mocking/stubbing.

Comment: @Fildor, how then would it be possible to test whether data returned by a service is correct? Currently the idea is to compare the retrieved result with an expected, locally stored result.

Comment: You would do that in a test for the implementation of `IElasticSearchService`. If there are more than one in your codebase, then there should be one test for each of them. But they wouldn't be _this_ test.

Comment: @Fildor. Okay. If I call ```GetProducts``` method from the 'base' class that implements ```IElasticSearchService``` (this class is also ultimately called in the current test, too), would that be a correct test for the implementation of ```IElasticSearchService```?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Testing an inheritance tree would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the interfaces(IProductService, IElasticSearchService) in a custom class then reference the classes to your ProductProvider's ctor. Before you reference them, create instance of both IElasticSearchService and IProductService in Searcher class

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly instantiate an Interface, but you can declare an object as an interface and then instantiate it as any class that implements that interface.

And, your new `ProductProvider` is being initialized with a null `_elasticSearchService` on your Searcher class.

Something like this:

```
private static readonly IElasticSearchService _elasticSearchService = new ClassImplementingElasticSearchServiceInterface();
```